# React: Problem passing state to setInterval

Tags: reactjs, state, settimeout, setinterval, setstate

- I'm trying to create a simple app that plays Youtube videos embedded in an iFrame.

  - When one video ends, the next starts
  - Some videos should only play for specific durations (this can be set using start and end params in the Youtube URL e.g. https://www.youtube.com/embed/iK2eOiSh6HI**?&start=22&end=28**"

I'm trying to use `setInterval` inside a function (`playNextVideo`) to play the next video after the duration of time between the start and end time. To do this, I'm parsing the URL and subtracting the end time from the start time.

```
this.setState({
        timer: (parseInt(parsedUrl.end, 10) - parseInt(parsedUrl.start, 10)) * 1000
      });
```

For example, if **end** is 28 seconds and **start** is 22 seconds, the result is 6 seconds.

I'm then passing `this.state.timer` into `setInterval` as the interval time, however, instead of `playNextVideo` being called for the duration specified in `setInterval` as expected, the function gets recalled at seemingly random times.

---

Here is the full code:

```
class App extends Component {

  state = {
    timer: 8000,
    urlList: {
      _01_3DAnimations: "https://www.youtube.com/embed/iK2eOiSh6HI?&start=22&end=28",
      _02_theRoom_hiDoggy: "https://www.youtube.com/embed/QgXYd6k251Q?&start=0&end=30 ",
      _03_flyingLotus_zodiacShit: "https://www.youtube.com/embed/0ScYz9sNaQk?&start=0&end=92"
    },
    activeUrl: "https://www.youtube.com/embed/Z1OLG7F3HD4?&start=22&end=28"

  }

  playNextVideo() {

    const keys = Object.keys(this.state.urlList);
    let parsedUrl = queryString.parse(encodeURI(this.state.activeUrl));

    setInterval(() => {
      const randomUrl = this.state.urlList[keys[keys.length * Math.random() << 0]];

      parsedUrl = queryString.parse(encodeURI(randomUrl));

      this.setState({
        timer: (parseInt(parsedUrl.end, 10) - parseInt(parsedUrl.start, 10)) * 1000
      });

      console.log("timer: ", this.state.timer);

      this.setState({
        activeUrl: randomUrl
      });

    }, this.state.timer);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.playNextVideo();
  }
```

Comment: I assume you meant to use `setTimeout` rather than `setInterval`, but that aside, this will be very brittle since it will cause the video to transition even if someone paused the previous video before it was finished.

Comment: I need to use ```setInterval``` as the function needs to be called over and over again. I'm going to handle pausing/sync issues further in development.

Comment: `setInterval` only works for a constant interval, whereas your recurrence does not have a constant interval. Each video takes a different amount of time to complete, so you just need to call `setTimeout` each time...

Comment: Ah, I didn't realise ```setInterval``` required a constant interval. This problem with ```setTimeout``` is that it only runs once. How would I get it to fire again after a video has ended?

Comment: You mind an answer using a function component?

Comment: I wouldn't mind at all :)

Comment: I think a better approach would be using [youtube's API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference) and use it to capture video ending events. I would advise you to take a look into the `onPlayerStateChange` function to trigger an action once a video is finished playing.

Comment: Thanks @JohnsonCherian, I didn't know this existed! I'll check it out :)

Answer (score 0):

you should create another method which will update state

```
  timer () {
      const randomUrl = this.state.urlList[keys[keys.length * Math.random() << 0]];

      parsedUrl = queryString.parse(encodeURI(randomUrl));

      this.setState({
        timer: (parseInt(parsedUrl.end, 10) - parseInt(parsedUrl.start, 10)) * 1000
      });

      console.log("timer: ", this.state.timer);

      this.setState({
        activeUrl: randomUrl
      });
  };


  playNextVideo() {
    const keys = Object.keys(this.state.urlList);
    let parsedUrl = queryString.parse(encodeURI(this.state.activeUrl));

    setInterval( timer, this.state.timer);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would reconsider your approach, as there's a few issues with the idea of [`setInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) here:

- It requires a constant delay
- Since it isn't being cleared, multiple calls will cause the function to be repeated for each interval

I'd suggest using [`setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) since it only results in one call after the timeout.

Note that you still need to address the issue of when the video is paused by the user before the timeout occurs:

```
function App({ urlList }) {
  const [activeUrl, setActiveUrl] = useState(urlList[0]);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const { start, end } = queryString.parse(encodeURI(activeUrl));
    const delay = parseInt(end, 10) - parseInt(start, 10) * 1000;

    const timeout = setTimeout(() => {
      const urls = urlList.filter(url => url !== activeUrl);
      const index = Math.floor(urls.length * Math.random());

      setActiveUrl(urls[index]);
    }, delay);

    // this will be called if the component unloads before the timeout
    return () => {
      clearTimeout(timeout);
    };
  }, [urlList, activeUrl, setActiveUrl]);

  ...
}
```

Then use the component like this:

```
<App urlList={[
  "https://www.youtube.com/embed/Z1OLG7F3HD4?&start=22&end=28",
  "https://www.youtube.com/embed/iK2eOiSh6HI?&start=22&end=28",
  "https://www.youtube.com/embed/QgXYd6k251Q?&start=0&end=30",
  "https://www.youtube.com/embed/0ScYz9sNaQk?&start=0&end=92"
]}/>
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer. Unfortunately I'm still having issues. If I ```console.log(activeUrl)``` it doesn't get logged for the duration of  ```delay``` but rather it gets logged over and over again at a rapid pace.

To test I swapped out ```delay``` for a hard coded 10 seconds, and the logs were more or less consistent at 10 seconds.

I've just noticed a comment by Johnson Cherian mentioning that there is built in Youtube API to handle this kind of thing, I'm going to look into that.